# Drupal Module (leaflet) not allowing to enable from admin panel

Tags: drupal

I am trying to implement leaflet maps on my website when I am trying to enable / ON module it is not allowing me to do it is in disabled mode (in grey color)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulsg3.png

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is my mistake.As it is appearing in the grey color I thought it is disabled.Because of dependencies on the module, it is just showing in grey color but the state is ON.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the modules that module is depending on. You must have all dependencies for the module you are trying to enable.

At modules page for every module you can see what modules are depending on it and on what are it's dependencies.

Comment: Everything which this module requires is enabled pls  find the screen I attached above

Comment: Strange. Did you use module version for your drupal version? I.e. maybe used Drupal 8 module on Drupal 7 site?